Why is GParted distributed as an ISO image? Is it to accommodate Linux needs as well as Windows needs?
I have a question about GParted (GNOME Partition Editor) being distributed as an ISO image. Can anyone explain why it is provided in this format?
Is the purpose to allow users to boot from this Debian-based OS image and manage partitions on their storage devices? In other words, is the idea to perform a boot from the partition where the GParted image is located? Have I understood this correctly?
So as a Linux user I don't need the ISO distributed version because I can use it as an application as part of my Debian-Based operation system (I'm using Ubuntu). So it's not necessary for me to boot from a dedicated partition with the ISO distributed version. But if a Windows user wants to manage the partitions in their system they would want to use the ISO image distribution version. Is it correct?
There is another thing that I'm missing here?

If the disk containing your root partition needs attention, you might not be able to boot (and even if you do, you might want to perform operations that are inadvisable on an in-use filesystem).  So being able to boot directly into the partitioner is useful in that scenario.


I have a question about GParted (GNOME Partition Editor) being distributed as an ISO image. Can anyone explain why it is provided in this format?
Is the purpose to allow users to boot from this Debian-based OS image and manage partitions on their storage devices? In other words, is the idea to perform a boot from the partition where the GParted image is located? Have I understood this correctly?

Yes, it's provided as a bootable image so that you could use it to work on your main OS partition (or your main OS disk in general).
This was even more important with earlier Windows versions, as e.g. WinXP still did not yet support resizing partitions through its own tools, much less moving them around, so there used to be many partition editors that worked this way; the popular Hiren's Boot CD used to have probably twenty such tools if not more (some based on WinPE, others on Linux, yet others booting into who-knows-what).

So as a Linux user I don't need the ISO distributed version because I can use it as an application as part of my Debian-Based operation system (I'm using Ubuntu).

The GParted Live system overall may be tailored to be more hardware-friendly (e.g. its graphical environment not requiring as much RAM as a Ubuntu live CD so you could boot it on much older machines), but the actual GParted software is the same as in any other Linux distribution.
Although it is likely that GParted Live will have a more up-to-date version of GParted and the associated tools such as ntfsprogs (which do the actual resizing) than Debian.

About what you wrote:
1.The GParted Live system overall may be tailored to be more hardware-friendly;;;
Is nice and i didn't consider that.
2.This was even more important with earlier Windows versions, as e.g. WinXP still did not yet support resizing partitions through its own tools;;; i didn't really get that, Today we can do it in windows? With the Disk managment tool? to mimic the gparted operations?


Today you can use Windows Disk Management or DISKPART to resize (shrink/expand) partitions "online", including even the system partition – although you still can't move them, but resizing is still very useful. In the past (when the GParted Live CD was devised) Windows could not do that.


It might be helpful to add a specific example of why this is needed for Linux. For example, if you want to clone an existing hard drive (here including SSDs) to a new one, the hard drives must be dismounted, so you can't use GParted in the existing system. The live system on the ISO allows you to clone the drive and make any changes to the UUIDs that might be required.

It has little to do with Windows or Linux. It has to do with the fact that when you are booted into any OS that is located on the hard drive whose partitions you want to change, you might not be able or it might at least not be a good idea to change its partitions.
Suppose you want to completely format your computer's main hard drive, then you obviously cannot do that while an OS that is located on that hard drive is running, whether that OS is Windows or Linux; you would destroy the thing that is doing the formatting while it's doing it.
Both for Windows and for Linux there are partition editors that run as an application on the ordinary operating system (GParted is an example of one for Linux), and you can use that to format e.g. external drives, SD cards, etc.; but you cannot use them to make arbitrary changes to your main hard drive that your OS is currently running from.
This is why you might need to run partition editors from external drives, so there are ISO images available that run nothing else than a partition editor.

Seems like after a little research I've found many reasons and the motivation that comes behind this ISO image distribution of gparted.
If we consider the ISO image as a bootable live CD/USB, it's contained a minimal Debian OS with a gparted application in it (preinstalled). It's allowing users to boot from this ISO image without relying on any installed OS!
The reliance on a specific OS is not required here. We can live boot from this specific ISO image and manage our partitions.
Linux users don't need to use this ISO version because we can install gparted app directly and use it (with root privileges).
But even as Linux users, we would need this ISO image in a rescue/repair mode when the OS cannot boot or some issues with the disk without relying on the OS, so we can fix the disk without relying on the current OS which is installed in the disk itself (which the data maybe corrupted).
And Windows users must use the ISO version (because gparted cannot run natively in Windows, because it's a Linux app).

The live ISO boot is required in situations when you need to change the partition(s) that are used under "normal circumstances". In use (mounted) partitions and disks cannot (normally at least) be modified.
